# Logrotate postrotate script fails to send SIGHUP to podman container

Tags: rsyslog, podman, logrotate

I have rsyslog running in an podman container. It is receiving logs and writing them to a mounted directory on the host. The rotation of this log files in done on the host, but for some reason logrotate fails

```
Mar 22 03:13:01 mars logrotate[42141]: ALERT exited abnormally with [1]
```

I checked SELinux, but audit log doesn't show anything.

This is the logrotate config:

```
/var/log/fw.log {
    compress
    compresscmd /bin/xz
    uncompresscmd /bin/unxz
    compressext .xz
    dateext
    maxage 1
    rotate 1
    daily
    notifempty
    missingok
    create 0660 fluent fluent
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/podman exec rsyslog-f5 /usr/bin/killall -HUP || false
    endscript
}
```

After the rotation, the file is copied to e.g. `/var/log/fw.log-20230322`, but rsyslog is not starting to write to the new file. If I run `/bin/podman exec rsyslog-f5 /usr/bin/killall -HUP` as root it works properly.

I already tried to add some debug output to the postrotate script

```
    postrotate
        /bin/podman exec rsyslog-f5 /usr/bin/killall -HUP rsyslogd 2>&1 > /tmp/postrotate.log || false
    endscript
```

but `/tmp/postrotate.log` was empty.
A dry run with `logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/fwlogs` doesn't show any errors.

Comment: is logrotate running as the same user as podman is?

Comment: No, it is running as root. But i think i got the problem, it seems that still SELinux was blocking. I've set it to permissive, and now it works. I have to review my policy.